# the linkOnPaste: false is set in @tiptap/extension-link, but still paste text it's converting it to a link in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, tiptap

I used the @tiptap/extension-link in the rich text editor in vue using the `tiptap` in Vue.
I have set the `linkOnPaste: false` but still when I paste a text it's converting it to a link.

Here is my code snippet.
`RichtextEditor.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="pl-1 pt-5" style="width: 100%">
    <div v-if="editor" style="border:1px solid; border-color: #EBEBEB;">
    <v-icon @click="setLink" :class="{ 'is-active': editor.isActive('link') }">
      mdi-link
    </v-icon>
    </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid; border-color: #EBEBEB;width: 100%">
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Editor, EditorContent } from "@tiptap/vue-2";
import StarterKit from "@tiptap/starter-kit";
import Underline from '@tiptap/extension-underline';
import TextAlign from '@tiptap/extension-text-align'
import Placeholder from '@tiptap/extension-placeholder'
import Link from '@tiptap/extension-link'

export default {
  name: "RichTextEditor",
  data() {
    return {
      editor: null,
    };
  },
  components: {
    "editor-content": EditorContent,
  },

  props: ["value", "proseHeight"],
  watch: {
    value(value) {
      console.log("VALUE", value)
      const isSame = this.editor.getHTML() === value;

      if (isSame) {
        return;
      }

      this.editor.commands.setContent(value, false);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.editor = new Editor({
    content: this.value || " ",
        editorProps: {
    attributes: {
      style: `height: ${this.proseHeight}; padding: 30px; overflow-y: scroll;`,
    },
  },
      extensions: [StarterKit, Underline,
      Link.configure({
          openOnClick: true,
          autolink: false,
          linkOnPaste: false,
          validate: href => /^https?:\/\//.test(href),
        }),
      Placeholder.configure({
          placeholder: 'Compose your Personal Message...',
          
        }),
        TextAlign.configure({
          types: ['heading', 'paragraph'],
        }),
        
        ],
      onUpdate: () => {
        this.$emit("input", this.editor.getHTML());
      },
    });
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.editor.destroy();
  },

  methods: {
      setLink() {
      const previousUrl = this.editor.getAttributes('link').href;
      let url = window.prompt('URL', previousUrl);

      if (url.includes("https://") === false && url.includes("http://") === false) {
        url = "https://" + url
        }

      // cancelled
      if (url === null) {
        return
      }

      // empty
      if (url === '') {
        this.editor
          .chain()
          .focus()
          .extendMarkRange('link')
          .unsetLink()
          .run()

        return
      }
      // update link
      this.editor
        .chain()
        .focus()
        .extendMarkRange('link')
        .setLink({ href: url })
        .run()
    },
  }
};
</script>

<style>

.ProseMirror:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.ProseMirror p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000
}

.ProseMirror ul {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
}

.ProseMirror {
    height: var(--proseHeight);
}
</style>
```

the other file `App.vue` where I used the `RichtextEditor.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <rich-editor v-model="value" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RichEditor from './components/RichtextEditor.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() => {
     return {
       value: "Initial Value"
     }
  },
  components: {
    "rich-editor": RichEditor
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A link will still be converted if you don't disable [autolink](https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/api/marks/link#autolink):

```js
Link.configure({
  autolink: false,
})
```